# Generate Visual Studio Project File to build a library with qmake syntax and where to find the project file?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, build, qmake, projects-and-solutions

I have an old script to create Visual Studio Project Files to build libraries. The syntax is

```
cd Kernel

cd core
qmake -t vclib

cd ccMigration
qmake -t vclib
cd ..
```

and so on for all of the different directories.

I understand why we use qmake and vclib, but what I am not sure is what is the use of -t in this line:

```
qmake -t vclib
```

Looking at this : http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qmake-platform-notes.html it says:

> Creating Visual Studio Project Files This section describes how to
>   import an existing qmake project into Visual Studio. qmake is able to
>   take a project file and create a Visual Studio project that contains
>   all the necessary information required by the development environment.
>   This is achieved by setting the qmake project template to either vcapp
>   (for application projects) or vclib (for library projects).
>
> This can also be set using a command line option, for example:
>
> `qmake -tp vc`

Why do they use -tp and is the old script syntax correct by using -t?

After I run the script it takes about 1/2 seconds and where can I find the project files for Visual Studio?

Finally, When I open the project files how can I build a library using Visual Studio? Can someone point me to a place where I can read some material?

Thank you for all the help!

Edit: I ran the script and it created .vcproj files in the directories that qmake was run. Example: In folder Kernel -> core it created ccCore.vcproj project file. When I open the file in Visual Studio 2017 it wanted me to perform a One-way upgrade that will automatically make functional changes to the project in order to open it. Is this okay?

Comment: `-t` is a command-line equivalent to TEMPLATE operator. See [qmake manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#template).

Comment: @matt thank you! I have missed this part of the qmake manual.